# How to replace text with value of attribute in Nifi ReplaceText processor?

Tags: replace, apache-nifi

I  want to replace some of the content of flowfile(based on rgex which I have) with the attribute value of attribute say var1 which is 123 (shown in image). I am doing this with Replace Text Processor in Nifi but the contents are not getting replaced instead the flow file is getting dropped.

[image: image of Data Flow]

Comment: please edit your question and add file content example, regular expression you use, and the replacement. ps: files are not dropped, they could be redirected to failure relationship if rexexp is wrong. check the doc: https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.6.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.ReplaceText/index.html

Comment: Please share your ReplaceContext confuguration and also a screenshot of the flow where this particular logic is handled would help.

Answer (score 19):

You can use the following flow as an example to achieve the regex replacement.

[image]

The individual processor configurations are below:

**GenerateFlowFile**: This generates a flow file with some content. In this case, the content is `This is my content`.

[image]

**UpdateAttribute**: This adds an attribute with key=`var1` and value=`123`.

[image]

**ReplaceText**: This looks for matches of the regex and replaces with the value of attribute `var1`. So, `This is my content` will be transformed to `This is my 123`.

[image]

**OriginalContent**: This is to see the actual content before the replace. It uses a `PutFile` processor.

[image]

**UpdatedContent**: This is to see the updated content. It uses a `PutFile` processor.

[image]

**Verification**

After the flow has run one time, you can verify the contents by looking at the generated files.

```
$ cat original/5601958271012409 
This is my content

$ cat updated/5601958271012409 
This is my 123
```